# How to create a dataframe with pandas without the header line, and make the first component of the string t

Tags: python, pandas, text

I have a .txt file with information about different people that looks like this:

```
"fullName": "Markus Graham",
"headline": "CEO ",
"company": "Orange",
"school": "Oxford ",
"location": "England",
(...)
"fullName": "Peter Hallsen",
"headline": "Co-Founder",
"company": "Telecom",
"school": "Cambridge ",
"location": "null",
(...)
```

I want to obtain a .csv file with the information organized this way:

```
FullName      |   Headline  |  Company   |  School     | Location
__________________________________________________________________
Markus Graham |   CEO       |  Orange    |  Oxford     |  England
Peter Hallsen |  Co-founder |  Telecom   |  Cambridge  |  null
```

I have tried to create a dataframe in pandas, but I get the following:

```
   Column 1                 |   Column 2         | Column 3 
______________________________________________________________________
"fullName": "Markus Graham" | "headline": "CEO " | "company": "Orange" (...)
```

I used the following code:

```
>> import pandas as pd                                                     
>> df=pd.read_table('text1.txt', sep=',')
>> df.to_excel(r'/Users/username/text1.xlsx')
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you add the code that you used to create your current output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression along with a `collections.defaultdict` here.  This makes a couple assumptions:

1) There are an equal number of values for each key

2) There are no quotes contained in any keys or values

---

***Setup***

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import re

d = defaultdict(list)
```

---

`re.findall` + `pd.DataFrame`

```
with open('test.csv') as infile:
  for line in infile:
    k, v = re.findall(r'\"([^"]+)\"', line)
    d[k].append(v)


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

```
        fullName    headline  company      school location
0  Markus Graham        CEO    Orange     Oxford   England
1  Peter Hallsen  Co-Founder  Telecom  Cambridge      null
```

Comment: ----> 3         k, v = re.findall(r'\"([^"]+)\"', line), ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Comment: Probably means you have empty lines, try replacing with a try-catch or checking the truthiness of the line

Answer (score 0):

You can read the data using read_csv and then reshape

```
import io

temp = """
"fullName": "Markus Graham",
"headline": "CEO ",
"company": "Orange",
"school": "Oxford ",
"location": "England",
"fullName": "Peter Hallsen",
"headline": "Co-Founder",
"company": "Telecom",
"school": "Cambridge ",
"location": "null"
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep = ':', header = None, names = ['column', 'value'])

df['tmp'] = (df['column']=='fullName').cumsum()

new_df = df.pivot(columns = 'column', index = 'tmp',  values = 'value').reset_index(drop = True).replace('"|,', '', regex = True)

new_df.columns.name = None


    company fullName        headline    location    school
0   Orange  Markus Graham   CEO         England     Oxford
1   Telecom Peter Hallsen   Co-Founder  null        Cambridge
```